# How to send correct request to Url urllib

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am currently trying to create an discord bot with a watch2gether command, where u send a url and he will automatically create a room with the Video preloaded.

Using the [Watch2Gether API Documentation](https://community.w2g.tv/t/watch2gether-api-documentation/133767) and other [Resources](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html) on how to fetch Urls with urllib, I managed to make it work somehow.

However I ran into mutiple issues while doing so. You can find the whole code [here](https://github.com/Hugejiji/discordbot/blob/main/main.py).

The first issue I had while using ***urllib.request.Request()*** in the following code, was that it always put out an *HTTP Error 400: Bad Request*.

My code:

```
from os import link
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json

items = []
url = "https://w2g.tv/rooms/create.json" 
data = { 'w2g_api_key': 'mzjdtcaj4nag0xf31lh919mjvnwmk8t3cgv51o0vo9397tcakjrsqx3sks3opjma',
        'share': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N6a-VLBa2I&t=798s',
        'bg_color': '#00ff00',
        'bg_opacity': '50' }      
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
update_data = { 'w2g_api_key': 'nt3ne3hg2m9lxr22eihoqlzjagsgfben2tpbhdogl47li8mln00c75zdpr5ypkho',
        'item_url': ''} 



class watchtogether():
 def source(self, link : str):
    data['share'] = link
    daten = urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode("utf-8")
    req = urllib.request.Request(url1, daten, headers)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
        source = response.read()
        dict = json.loads(source)
        items.append(dict['streamkey'])
    return items[0]
```

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/Desktop/Discordbot/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/Desktop/Discordbot/main.py", line 178, in w2g
    await ctx.send("w2g room created, here ist your link: https://w2g.tv/rooms/" + watchtogether().source(url))
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/Desktop/Discordbot/main.py", line 147, in source
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/Desktop/Discordbot/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/Desktop/Discordbot/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/Desktop/Discordbot/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

> Blockquote
```

Although the w2g Documentations specifically states that I have to "Make sure to set the content type of your request to application/json" and if I understand this correctly, the only way to pass headers as a parameter is using urllib.request.Request(), so I tried something else.

I got rid of using urllib.request.Request() and replaced it with just urllib.request.urlopen(). This seems to work perfectly so far but when I try to immediately create a new room with a new Video to preload, it is still opening the "old" room and loads a random Video w2g has set as default.

Reading through the Watch2Gether API Documentation I noticed that you can actually update a current room so that it plays the new URL that you pass in. You can see what I did in the following Snippet:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json

items = []
url = "https://w2g.tv/rooms/create.json" 
data = { 'w2g_api_key': 'TOKEN',
        'share': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N6a-VLBa2I&t=798s',
        'bg_color': '#00ff00',
        'bg_opacity': '50' }      
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
update_data = { 'w2g_api_key': 'TOKEN',
        'item_url': ''} 



class watchtogether():
 def source(self, link):
    data['share'] = link
    daten = urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode("utf-8")
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url , daten, 100) as response:
        source = response.read()
        dict = json.loads(source)
        items.append(dict['streamkey'])
    return items[0]

 def update(self, url):    
     update_data['item_url'] = url 
     url_in = f"https://w2g.tv/rooms/{items[0]}/sync_update"
     daten1 = urllib.parse.urlencode(update_data).encode("utf-8")
     urllib.request.urlopen(url_in, daten1)
```

First things first, it does not cause any Errors, but when I call the method update() it just resets the currently playing Video so that it repeats itself again, instead of adding a the new one.

My question is what exactly do I have to request from the URL to make this work, as I don't really need any file-like object as response (for example getting json-string and extracting the streamkey to create a new room).

Also, I thought headers are an important parameter for sending a request, yet I managed to ignore them somehow.
And how would u fix the Error urllib.request.Request() created.

I know that's a lot of input to this, but I really want to understand what it is I am doing wrong and how fetching Internet Resources actually works.
Feel free to critique everything, including the way I structured this question.

Comment: Please clarify _only resets the currently playing source instead of adding a new one_... Since we do not have your API TOKEN, we cannot re-create your problem as part of a [mcve] ... Also, you define a class and two functions, but where do you actually call them?

Comment: "but when I call the method update() it just resets the currently playing Video so that it repeats itself again, instead of adding a the new one" I hope that clarifies it a bit. 

And I thought I linked this https://github.com/Hugejiji/discordbot/blob/main/main.py, I call them inside the 
bot.command()

async def w2g(ctx, url):
   await ctx.send("w2g room created, here ist your link: https://w2g.tv/rooms/" + watchtogether().source(url))

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the Youtube API or Discord, but the urllib usage seems fine at a glance... You definitely shouldn't put your API key into the post, though